# Unable to add member variables to c++ class

Tags: c++

I have a class header (class.h) and implementation (class.cpp). I have several member variables declared in the class.h and I am using them without any issues in class.cpp. I am now trying to add 3 more member variables in the class.h:

```
double a;
double b;
double c;
```

I am initializing these 3 guys similar to rest of the member variables in class.cpp like this:

```
Class::Class()
{
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    c = 0;
    //constructor body
}
```

This code compiles fine but segfaults on execution. Valgrind says that I have an invalid write of size 8 bytes on the line "b = 0;" and wherever else a,b,c are being used. There are no issues when these 3 variables are removed. What might be the problem here? There is enough memory available for the program. Thank you!

EDIT:
I have added the class definition here:

```
class AWidget: public QGraphicsView
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    AWidget( QWidget * parent = 0 );
    virtual ~AWidget();

    //public functions

private:
    Q_DISABLE_COPY ( AlignmentWidget )

    void updateWidget();
    void updateArrowsVisibility();
    void updateAimLineItemVisibility();

    double x;
    double y;
    double z;

    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    QGraphicsPixmapItem *item;
    QGraphicsPixmapItem *aErrorItem;
    QGraphicsEllipseItem *circle;

    QGraphicsLineItem *LineItem0;
    QGraphicsLineItem *LineItem1;
    QGraphicsLineItem *LineItem2;
    QGraphicsLineItem *LineItem3;
    QGraphicsLineItem *LineItem4;

    double a;
    double b;
    double c;

};

AWidget::AWidget(QWidget *parent)
    scene( 0 ),
    item( 0 ),    
    aErrorItem( 0 ),
    circle(0),
    LineItem0( 0 ),
    LineItem1(0),
    LineItem2(0),
    LineItem3(0),
    LineItem4(0)
{
    //init stuff like scene = new QGraphicsScene(); etc..
    a=0;
    b=0;
    c=0;
}
```

Comment: Did you properly recompile all your solution / project, or at least all the files that used `class.h` ? If not, that can cause issues with pre-existing object files that do not consider the modifications you have added.

Comment: yes, I have cleaned and rebuilt the class

Comment: Showing us the header file the class is defined in would help.

Comment: @ameya Not just the class, but everything that uses the class.

Comment: @ameya Not just the class - I'm really talking about any file in your project that might use it.

Comment: Anything that includes `class.h`, directly or indirectly, will need to be rebuilt.

Comment: Are you allocating a new class? Sounds like you're attempting something extremely unusual; as if you're writing to memory you don't own!

Comment: Are you initializing the member like `Class::Class():a(0), b(0), c(0){}` ?

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @dans3itz: I don't think I'm attempting anything unusual, it's just adding a member variable.

Comment: @PierreFourgeaud: I tried it that way too, did not work.

Comment: @ameya if none of the suggested ways work, you'll have to provide a more lengthy piece of code as your bug might be more intricate than originally guessed. I still strongly recommend that you rebuild the entirety of your project - just to be sure. :)

Comment: Can you provide the whole class definition, and a block of code that reads the member and crashes?

Comment: You need to provide more code for us to help you

Comment: I have added the class definition here for your reference.

Comment: You should try to make a *real* clean rebuild: delete all files created by `uic` or `moc`, all objects, and rebuild.

Comment: @ameya So you tried an initializer list and it too "did not work" ? I wish I knew what that meant. How is this instance *created* in the first place? On the heap via `new` ? An automatic stack variable? Thus the reason for the request for code that *creates* this object and thus exhibits the real problem. And the `//init stuff like scene = new QGraphicsScene(); etc..` does that have any code behind it? I.e. is there anything *above* those member assignments (and there couldn't be if this were in an initializer list).

Comment: My bad. The class in question was included in another part of the project which was not getting cleaned. I manually cleaned everything as suggested by @Synxis and it is not crashing now. Thank you all!

Comment: @WhozCraig: I meant that the initializer list also crashed the application. Yes I am creating the instance on the heap using new.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing a `:` in your constructor definition. Try this:

```
AWidget::AWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    scene( 0 ),
```

Comment: I'm sorry I missed the semicolon in the question. I have included it in the code.